# Component does not emit event after async vuelidate validation line

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vitest, vuelidate

I'm using Vue 3.3.* and Vuelidate 2.0.*. I'm using setup + composition API, TypeScript and TailwindCSS.

I'm creating unit tests using vitest and have a form in a component that I want to check if emits a submit event from that component when the submit button is clicked. In my unit test however, the emit function doesn't work if it emits the event *after* this line of code: `const isValid = await v$.value.$validate();`

This is the vitest:

```
    it("should emit submit event when submit button is clicked", async () => {
        const nameInput = wrapper.find("input#name");
        const emailInput = wrapper.find("input#email");
        const messageInput = wrapper.find("textarea#message");

        // First fill out the inputs with valid data
        await nameInput.setValue("John Doe");
        await emailInput.setValue("john.doe@example.com");
        await messageInput.setValue("A 10+ character long message.");

        await wrapper.find("form").trigger("submit");
        expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty("submit");
    });
```

Here is my form:

```html
        <form ref="formElement" id="contact-form" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" class="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="name" class="text-lg mb-2">Name</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    @change="v$.name.$reset()"
                    :class="inputCss + ' ' + (v$.name.$error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-white')"
                />
                <span v-if="v$.name.$error" class="ml-2 italic text-red-500">{{ v$.name.$errors[0].$message }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="email" class="text-lg mb-2">Email</label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    @change="v$.email.$reset()"
                    :class="inputCss + ' ' + (v$.email.$error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-white')"
                />
                <span v-if="v$.email.$error" class="ml-2 italic text-red-500">{{ v$.email.$errors[0].$message }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="message" class="text-lg mb-2">Message</label>
                <textarea
                    id="message"
                    name="message"
                    @change="v$.message.$reset()"
                    :class="inputCss + ' ' + (v$.message.$error ? 'border-red-500' : 'border-white')"
                ></textarea>
                <span v-if="v$.message.$error" class="ml-2 italic text-red-500">{{
                    v$.message.$errors[0].$message
                }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-center">
                <button type="submit" class="hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-900 duration-75" :class="inputCss">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and the handleSubmit function:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
    if (!formElement.value) return;
    
    const newFormData = new FormData(formElement.value);
    const data = Object.fromEntries(newFormData.entries());
    Object.assign(formData, data);

    // This works:
    // emit("submit", toRaw(formData));
    const isValid = await v$.value.$validate();

    // This doesn't work:
    // emit("submit", toRaw(formData));
    if (!isValid) return;
    
    // This is how it should be, but it's not working
    emit("submit", toRaw(formData));

    // This prints out fine when running the test:
    console.log("Should have submitted now, but hasn't!")
}
```

So I have located the problem to this line: `const isValid = await v$.value.$validate();` and I checked if the values are correct (they are. isValid is true). I have also tried adding `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` in different places to no avail.

What is going on here and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises . There's race condition, you need to "wait and wait a bit more", something that nextTick doesn't do. In case there are async validators, this needs to be treated additionally

Comment: Awesome @EstusFlask That solved it! I found that the package @vue/test-utils already has a flushPromises method, so I don't need to add any additional packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @EstusFlask said in their comment to the post, I need to flush the promises which can either be done with the flush-promises package, or with @vue/test-utils: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#flushPromises